# Update image name in the database with php

Tags: php, sql, database

**[EDITED WITH SOLUTION]** Noob error, it was only missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form

I don't know why my code suddenly stop to work. I created a CRUD app with php and mySQL. Now when I try to update the image name in the database I get no result. I'm pretty sure the code I'm using is correct but maybe I'm missing something

The DB table has a column named 'image' where I store the image name with its extension (ex. logo.jpg)

This is the update.php that let me change some values. If I try to update every other field I get no error and everything works, but I'm not able to change the image. What am I missing? I'm really new with php and I don't know if I accidentally miswrote something, thanks in advance! (Let me know if more code is needed)

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';

$msg = '';

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        // Posted Values
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $preview=$_POST['preview'];
        $main=$_POST['main'];
        $created = $_POST['created'];

        $imageName=$_FILES['immagine']['name'];

        // Query for Insertion
        $data = [
            'title' => $title,
            'category' => $category,
            'preview' => $preview,
            'main' => $main,
            'id' => $_GET['id'],
            'created' => $created,
            'immagine' => $imageName,
        ];

        $sql="UPDATE post SET title=:title, category=:category, preview=:preview, main=:main, created=:created, image=:immagine WHERE id=:id";

        //Prepare Query for Execution
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        // Query Execution
        $stmt->execute($data);

    

        header('Location: preview.php?id=' . $_GET['id']);
  }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
    $contact = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container_create">
            <div class="topnav">
                <a href="preview.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"><img src="IMG/Back_icon.svg" alt="menu" id="back_icon"></a>
                <img src="IMG/Logo_orizontale.svg" alt="menu" id="hyperink_logo">
            </div>

            <p id="titolo_create">Impostazione Pagina</p>

            <div class="box_create">
                <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post" id="form_create">

                    <label class="labels_create">Data</label>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="created" class="inputs_create" id="myDatetimeField" value="<?=$contact['created']?>">

                    <label class="labels_create">Titolo del Articolo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="inputs_create" id="title" value="<?=$contact['title']?>">

                    <label class="labels_create">Categoria</label>
                    <input type="text" name="category" class="inputs_create" id="cat" value="<?=$contact['category']?>">

                    <label class="labels_create">Descrizione</label>
                    <textarea type="text" name="preview" id="preview" class="inputs_create" row="5" col="50" onkeyup ="limite_caratteri()"><?=$contact['preview']?></textarea>


                    <label class="labels_create">Contenuto del Articolo</label>
                    <div class="text_editor">
                        <textarea id="main" name="main" rows="5" cols="50"><?=$contact['main']?></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="file" id="immagine" name="immagine" class="inputs_create_file" accept="image/*"><span><?php echo $contact['image']?></span>

                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Salva Modifiche" class="btn_create">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: It was working before but now it's not... so, what did you change?

Comment: I really don't know, because I made some test without the image field and when I tried to re-write the code it didn't work. I'm really confused @ADyson

Comment: Not the solution to your issue, but note that `header` does not terminate the script, you should add a `die()` after the header is set to prevent the rest of the script from executing.

Comment: Just noticed the issue, your `form` doesn't have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, the file will not be posted without this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: AH! Sorry, I'm working only on the backend of this code and I totally forgot to check if the enctype was there -.-'
Thanks a lot @Geoffrey I would have probably spent a day after this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is failing to post the image because you have not set the `enctype` attribute, by default HTML forms post as plain text and will not include any binary data such as an image upload. To correct this you need to set the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`.

For example:

```html
<form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post" id="form_create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See: [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more information.